# Python add class to __mro__ at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass, method-resolution-order

I have seen questions which allow adding a base class at runtime, but I have a more specific question trying to add a base class in a deeper hierarchy by use of a metaclass.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, special=False, **kwargs):
        if special:
            cls = cls.__class__(cls.__name__ + Special.__name__, (Special,), {})
        return super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)    

class Base(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      print('construct Base')    

class Special(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      print('construct Special')    

class Concrete(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      print('construct Concrete')    

class Specific(Concrete):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      print('construct Specific')    

c = Specific(special=True)
print(c.__class__.__mro__) # (Specific, Special, Base, Object)

# construct Base
# construct Special
# (<class 'SpecificSpecial'>, <class 'Special'>, <class 'Base'>, <class 'object'>)
```

I would like to be able to add the `Special` class to my hierarchy at runtime in the metaclass `__call__` function. But this will overwrite the `Concrete` base class, essentially cutting it out. I am not sure how to insert this base properly. Also, I lose the constructor of `Specific` when trying to create a new class. I really *only* want to insert a class into the `__mro__` with no side effects. Possible?

Comment: So inherit from `(cls, Special)` or `(Special, cls)`, instead of just `(Special,)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing out the current class hierarchy because you are constructing a new class from a different base class altogether. If `Special` is to be a mix-in, **add** it to the current class hierarchy. Inherit from both `Special` and `cls`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, special=False, **kwargs):
        if special:
            cls = cls.__class__(cls.__name__ + Special.__name__, (Special, cls), {})
        return super(Meta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The output then becomes:

```
>>> c = Specific(special=True)
construct Base
construct Concrete
construct Specific
construct Special
>>> print(c.__class__.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.SpecificSpecial'>, <class '__main__.Special'>, <class '__main__.Specific'>, <class '__main__.Concrete'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
```

This puts `Special` before the other classes in the hierarchy. Swap the base class order if you need `Special` to come after `Specific` and `Concrete` (but before `Base`) instead:

```
cls = cls.__class__(cls.__name__ + Special.__name__, (cls, Special), {})
```

Note that this creates a new class *every time you create an instance*. You may want to cache the classes to at least avoid a proliferation of class objects.